# jQuery child element selection

Tags: jquery

May be there are similar post inhere, but I couldn't understand the plenty of them. My question is that I have

```
       <aside class="main-aside-info">
            <ul id="main-aside-info-ul">
                <img id="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /><li>Title</li>
                <img id="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /><li>Title</li>
                <img id="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /><li>Title</li>
                <img id="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /><li>Title</li>
                <img id="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /><li>Title</li>
                <img id="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /><li>Title</li>
                <img id="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /><li>Title</li>
                <img id="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /><li>Title</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
```

Each of this img's have visibility hidden and I want to make a good looking function about it so that I may be have to use child-class selectors or something of this kind. I tried doing it using stupid code like :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#one").click(function(){
    $("#triangle1").css('visibility', 'visible');

});
    $("#two").click(function(){
    $("#triangle2").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
            $("#two").click(function(){
    $("#triangle2").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
                    $("#two").click(function(){
    $("#triangle2").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
                            $("#two").click(function(){
    $("#triangle2").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
                                    $("#two").click(function(){
    $("#triangle2").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

});

And etc.. but this code is not optimal I suppose (even in here, I tried giving different id's). So can you help me about my function?

Comment: what is #one post complete html

Comment: `id` values **must** be unique. You can't have more than one element with the same `id` (`id="triangle"` is repeated on multiple elements in your HTML).

Comment: Also, it would help to explain what your goal is. Right now, I don't really get what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell I put #one on the first <li> element but made changes and forgot to put it. My idea was i don't want to use id's and classes

Comment: And yes id's must be uniqeu My bad. My ideas is when i click on some <li> element to show the given <img> element that stands before the element clicked

Comment: I can make it hard way.. with diferent id's and large jquery code but don't want to do it like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we have to make the HTML valid. Two major issues:

1. `id` values **must** be unique
2. You can't put `img` elements directly inside a `ul`; the only valid children of `ul` and `ol` are `li` and `template`

So let's put the `img` elements *inside* the `li`s, and use `class` rather than `id`:

```
<aside class="main-aside-info">
    <ul id="main-aside-info-ul">
        <li><img class="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img class="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img class="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img class="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img class="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img class="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img class="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img class="triangle" src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Then you can select them with the `:eq` pseudo-selector:

```
$("aside .triangle:eq(2)"); // Finds the third
```

or the `.eq` function:

```
$("aside .triangle").eq(2); // Finds the third
```

Or actually, you don't even need a class if you key off the parent's `id`:

```
<aside class="main-aside-info">
    <ul id="main-aside-info-ul">
        <li><img src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
        <li><img src="images/triangle.png" />Title</li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Then:

```
$("#main-aside-info-ul img:eq(2)"); // Finds the third
```

or the `.eq` function:

```
$("#main-aside-info-ul img").eq(2); // Finds the third
```

Comment: ok man that helped me but i  have an aditional question how can i select multiple id's in one () like $("#1", "#2")

Comment: @user3351517: If you're using the pseudo-selector, exactly the same way, with a comma. If you're using `.eq`, the simplest way is probably to replace `.eq` with `.filter` and pass in a function that returns `true` for the indexes you want and `false` for the ones you don't. This will give you the second and fourth: `$("aside .triangle").filter(function(index) { return index === 1 || index === 3; });` There's also `.slice` and a bunch of other useful things [in the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com).